# Fill array with json response

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to populate array in my validation code with distinct values from one column, and logic was that on focus on certain element I would send ajax request and populate array with JSON response. But I'm still a novice in JQuery and it seems I cant get it right, so if anyone can help.

```
$('input#search').on("focus", function(){

        $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                dataType: "json",
                url:"ajax_php/get_distinct_cities.php",
                    success:function(data){
                        $.each( data.city, function( i, itemData ) {
                           cities[i] = itemData;
                        });
                    }
                 });

    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("pickante");

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM uc_items";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $cities = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       $cities[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($cities);
    ?>
```

JSON Print:

```
[{"city":"Belgrade"},{"city":"Novi Sad"}]
```

Comment: `data` is an array, it doesn't have a `.city` property.  `$.each(data, function(i, itemData){ cities[i] = itemData.city; });`.

Comment: Rookie mistake, but I'm rookie anyway. Thx mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop the array and push

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cities.push(data[i].city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As timeJV said just loop the array and add the cities to you array, here is an example of how it will be using the `$.each`, but the previous answer will do the work.

```
 $.each(data, function( i, itemData ) {
                     cities.push(itemData.city);
          });
```